# Bluetooth connecting problems

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I use this code to connect an android device to an other device but there is no possibility to make this happen there is always a problem with the UUID.

There is the code of the BluetoothConnectionService

```
package com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by Lukas on 08.01.2017.
 */

public class BluetoothConnectionService {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectionServ";

    private static final String appName = "MYAPP";

    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    private final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Context mContext;

    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;

    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private UUID deviceUUID;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        start();
    }


    /*
    This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
    like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread(){
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try{
                tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(appName, MY_UUID_INSECURE);

                Log.d(TAG, "AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG, "run: AcceptThread Running.");

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try{
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket start.....");

                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket accepted connection.");

            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            //talk about this is in the 3rd
            if(socket != null){
                connected(socket,mmDevice);
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread ");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Canceling AcceptThread.");
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: Close of AcceptThread ServerSocket failed. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }

    }

    /*
     This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     succeeds or fails.
    */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
            mmDevice = device;
            deviceUUID = uuid;
        }

        public void run(){
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread ");

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: "
                        +MY_UUID_INSECURE );
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket " + e.getMessage());
            }

            mmSocket = tmp;

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket " + e1.getMessage());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE );
            }

            //will talk about this in the 3rd video
            connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Closing Client Socket.");
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: close() of mmSocket in Connectthread failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }



    /*
     Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
    */
    public synchronized void start() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     AcceptThread starts and sits waiting for a connection.
     Then ConnectThread starts and attempts to make a connection with the other devices AcceptThread.
     **/

    public void startClient(BluetoothDevice device,UUID uuid){
        Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started.");

        //initprogress dialog
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"Connecting Bluetooth"
                ,"Please Wait...",true);

        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuid);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    /*
     Finally the ConnectedThread which is responsible for maintaining the        BTConnection, Sending the data, and
     receiving incoming data through input/output streams respectively.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting.");

            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            //dismiss the progressdialog when connection is established
            try{
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected: Starting.");

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    /*
     Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     @param out The bytes to write
     @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
    */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;

        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
        //perform the write
        mConnectedThread.write(out);
    }

}
```

This is my main File:

```
package com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

public class NappyCheck extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public Button button1;
    Button button2;

    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    Button button5;

    EditText etSend;

    BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;
    private static final UUID My_UUID_INSECURE = UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");
    BluetoothDevice mBTDevice;

    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    public DeviceListAdapter mDeviceListAdapter;
    ListView lvNewDevices;


    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;


    //1BroadcastReceiver Bluetooth enable/Disable
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (state) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };


    //2BroadcastReceiver Bluetooth Sichtbarkeit
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {
                int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (mode) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverable Enabled");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverable Disabled. Able to receive connections");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverable Disabled. Not able to receive connections");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connecting...");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connected.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };


    //3BroadcastReceiver Bluetooth andere Geräte Finden
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.");

            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mBTDevices.add(device);
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
                mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapter_view, mBTDevices);
                lvNewDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
            }
        }
    };


    //4BroadcastReceiver Bluetooth andere Geräte Finden
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver4 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                //case1
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED");
                    mBTDevice = mDevice;
                }
                //case2
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING");
                }
                //case3
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE");
                }

            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: called.");
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nappy_check);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        lvNewDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevices);
        mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();
        etSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        //Broadcast when bond changes
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4, filter);

        lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                enableDisableBT();
            }
        });



        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startConnection();
            }
        });

        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                byte[] bytes = etSend.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
                mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
            }
        });
    }

    //method for starting connection
    public void startConnection() {
        startBTConnection(mBTDevice, My_UUID_INSECURE);
    }

    public void startBTConnection(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startBTConnection: Initializing RFCOM Bluetooth Connection");

        mBluetoothConnection.startClient(device, uuid);
    }

    public void enableDisableBT() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities.");
        }

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: enabling BT.");
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBTIntent);

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: disabling BT.");
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }
    }


    public void Sichtbarkeit(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnEnableDisable_Discoverable: Sichtbar machen für 300 sek.");

        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2, intentFilter);
    }

    public void btnDiscover(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.");

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Canceling discovery.");

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
    }


    private void checkBTPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            int permissionCheck = this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
            permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
            if (permissionCheck != 0) {

                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP.");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: you Clicked on a Device");
        String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(i).getName();
        String deviceAdress = mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceName = " + deviceName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceAdress = " + deviceAdress);

        //create Bond
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to Pair with " + deviceName);
            mBTDevices.get(i).createBond();

            mBTDevice = mBTDevices.get(i);
            mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(this);
        }
    }


}
```

And this is the Log file after I push the connection Button:

```
01-09 18:55:28.925 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.
01-09 18:55:28.949 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP.
01-09 18:55:29.110 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: onReceive: ACTION FOUND.
01-09 18:55:29.120 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: onReceive: [TV]Samsung LED40: 5C:F6:DC:53:3B:85
01-09 18:55:29.423 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: onReceive: ACTION FOUND.
01-09 18:55:29.426 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: onReceive: [HTS]H5500: BC:14:85:58:2E:13
01-09 18:55:30.398 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: onReceive: ACTION FOUND.
01-09 18:55:30.402 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: onReceive: LUKASSPC: 34:DE:1A:52:2D:8E
01-09 18:55:34.626 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: onItemClick: you Clicked on a Device
01-09 18:55:34.634 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: onItemClick: deviceName = LUKASSPC
01-09 18:55:34.635 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: onItemClick: deviceAdress = 34:DE:1A:52:2D:8E
01-09 18:55:34.635 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: Trying to Pair with LUKASSPC
01-09 18:55:34.649 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: start
01-09 18:55:34.663 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
01-09 18:55:34.668 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: 8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66
01-09 18:55:34.670 2482-2770/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: run: AcceptThread Running.
01-09 18:55:34.670 2482-2770/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: run: RFCOM server socket start.....
01-09 18:55:38.704 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/MainActivity: startBTConnection: Initializing RFCOM Bluetooth Connection
01-09 18:55:38.704 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: startClient: Started.
01-09 18:55:38.799 2482-2482/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: ConnectThread: started.
01-09 18:55:38.802 2482-2832/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test I/BluetoothConnectionServ: RUN mConnectThread 
01-09 18:55:38.802 2482-2832/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: 8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66
01-09 18:55:38.811 2482-2832/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
01-09 18:55:38.843 2482-2832/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: run: Closed Socket.
01-09 18:55:38.844 2482-2832/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: 8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66
01-09 18:55:38.844 2482-2832/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: connected: Starting.
01-09 18:55:38.850 2482-2832/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test D/BluetoothConnectionServ: ConnectedThread: Starting.
01-09 18:55:38.853 2482-2833/com.example.lukas.nappycheck_test E/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Error reading Input Stream. socket closed
```

My problem is it is not able to use the UUID, but it isn't only this UUID. I tried it with another UUID, too.

I'm also not able to connect to any bluetooth device because of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable that holds the UUIDs

```
ParcelUuid[] mDeviceUUIDs;
```

get the UUIDs for the device you've chosen

```
  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: you Clicked on a Device");
        String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(i).getName();
        String deviceAdress = mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceName = " + deviceName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceAdress = " + deviceAdress);

        //create Bond
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to Pair with " + deviceName);
            mBTDevices.get(i).createBond();

            mBTDevice = mBTDevices.get(i);

            //****ADDED THIS TO YOUR CODE:
            mDeviceUUIDs = mBTDevice.getUuids();
            //***************************

            mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(this);
        }
    }
```

Now send the UUIDs to the ConnectionService

```
    public void startConnection() {
        startBTConnection(mBTDevice, mDeviceUUIDs);
    }
```

Inside yourBluetoothConnectionService class you will need to change a few things:
First change the 'Startclient' method to accept ParcelUuid[] uuids instead of a single UUID

```
public void startClient(BluetoothDevice device,ParcelUuid[] uuids){
        Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started.");

        //initprogress dialog
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"Connecting Bluetooth"
                ,"Please Wait...",true);

        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuids);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }
```

You will now need to alter ConnectThread to accept the ParcelUuid[]'s instead of a single UUID. 
Then you will need to write a loop to iterate through each of the UUIDs until a connection is established.
I will leave this part to you :)

-->> Alternatively, you can just get the UUIDs from your main file, print them to the log, then just try each
one manually until a connection gets made. IE: Change the 'My_UUID_INSECURE' in your main file to each one of
the UUIDs from the log until it works.

Hope this helps and goodluck :)